# Captcha reload doesn't work in IE 9

Tags: javascript, function, captcha, reload

I have a simple javascript function works perfectly in chrome, but in Internet Explorer don't do anything. I can't figure it out why.

The function:

```
function captcha()
{
img = document.getElementById("captcha");
img.src = "captcha.asp";
}
```

I have a form in the html, where is a button with an onClick event which call the captcha function.

Comment: can you share generated HTML markup for captcha `img` tag?

Comment: <img src="captcha.asp" alt="CAPTCHA" id="captcha" width="140" height="30" />

Answer (score 0):

One possible thing is a caching problem. Did you check the request and response.
Try to add a random argument with the src url to avoid caching.

```
img.src = "captcha.asp&id=12a4";
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution which works properly in chrome, firefox and internet explorer.

I've put the img tag into an iframe with captcha ID, and with the js function, i reload this iframe.

```
document.getElementById("captcha").src=document.getElementById("captcha").src;
```

Problem solved.